# declaration of âoperator<<â as non-function

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, friend-function

i have tried everything , i can't understand why it's not working.

> g++ throw :
>
> Queue.H:53: error: declaration of âoperator<<â as non-function
>
> Queue.H:53: error: expected â;â before â<â token
>
> Queue.H:59: error: expected â;â before âprivateâ

the code is:

```
#ifndef _Queue_H_
#define _Queue_H_
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

template <class T, int size>

class Queue
{
public:
    Queue():_Num(0){
        T Arr=new T[size];
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
            Arr[i]=0;}
    ~Queue(){
        for (int i=0;i<_Num;i++)
            delete Arr_[i];
        delete [] Arr_;
    }
    bool IsEmpty() const{return !_Num ;}
    bool IsFull() const{return (_Num==size);}
    void count() const{return _Num;}
    T& Top() const {
        if(!IsEmpty())
            return Arr_[0];
        else
            throw("empty");
    }
    void operator << (const T & item ) {
        if(!IsFull()){
            Arr_[_Num+1]=item;
            _Num++;}
        else
            throw("full");}
    
    T  operator >> (T & item) {
        if(IsEmpty())
            throw("empty");
        
        item=Arr_[0];
        delete Arr_[0];
        for(int i=1;i<_Num;i++)
            Arr_[i-1]=Arr_[i];
        _Num--;
        return item;}
    
    T operator [] (const T &number){
        return (number<size) ?Arr_[number]:throw("overload");}
    
    friend ostream & operator << <T,size>(ostream & or ,const Queue<T,size> &a){
        for(int i=0;i<a._Num;i++)
            or<<a.Arr_[i];
        return or;
    }
    
private:
    T Arr_[size];
    int _Num;
};
```

Comment: Coudl you please fix your indentation? This is unreadable code.

Comment: please highlight the important lines

Comment: A good hint is make your non-template version of Queue working first, the add template to it.

Comment: _Num is a bad choice of naming, see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

A friend function should be defined outside, you could hit issues like [Access friend function defined in class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785886/access-friend-function-defined-in-class) . You should just leave a friend declaration within the class and define the function outside the class.

But your error comes due to the way you name your template variables.

Instead of

```
friend ostream & operator << <T,size>(ostream & or ,const Queue<T,size> &a){
```

try just

```
friend ostream & operator << (ostream & or ,const Queue<T,size> &a){
```

p.s. `_Num` - [Bad Idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/1520364)

Comment: Yeah yeah, you're both on target. sry for the cross take on terms, Karthik. totally my bad. I'll drop comment. Been a long day.

Comment: Why complicate it so much? Simply say: *"friend functions are declared as friend in the class, and defined elsewhere*". IMO the important distinguishing point is *declaration* and *definition*.

Comment: @WhozCraig no worries, always glad to improve my c++ jargon

Comment: i have tried to write the friend function outside and changed what you sayed it's still not working.

Comment: @oren *both* answers should work, but Karthik's is less invasive and more inline with what you were originally going for. If it works for you (and it should), then excellent.

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about tight coupling like me, you are especially concerned about `friend` (because that's the tightest coupling C++ has to offer). That said, there is a view of `operator<<` that makes it easy to implement, inside the class, without any friend declarations:

Simply put, `operator<<` for ostream is a mere beautification for a simple print method. And it is only because of this beautification (chaining `os << a << b << c...` calls) that the operator can't be a method of the class it should be part of. So many people resort to a friend declaration of that operator, which imo is an encapsulation breaking ugly workaround. So what can you do?

```
template <class T, int size>
class Queue
{
public:
    /**
     * Here comes the method. Inside the class, were it should be, 
     * having all the access it needs. 
     * No template-specialization-friend-declaration needed.
     */
    ostream & printToStream(ostream & or) const 
    { 
        for(int i=0;i<a._Num;i++)
            or<<Arr_[i];
        return or;
    }

private:
    T Arr_[size];
    int _Num;
};

/**
 * Here comes operator<<. It is what it really is:
 * Just a beautification, nothing more, no additional functionality.
 */
template <class T, int size> 
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Queue<T,size> const& q)
{ return q.printToStream(os); }
```

See? No big deal at all. If you do that often, and if your method is called printToStream every time, you can make it a template:

```
template <class Printable>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Printable const& p)
{ return p.printToStream(os); }
```

And if you want to get fancy, you can enable_if that operator [only if it has that member function](http://www.gockelhut.com/c++/articles/has_member). No more "friend operator<< how should I do that again?", just implement printToStream, and the beautification-operator<< already exists.