# Custom manipulator compiles with Visual C++ but not g++/clang

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++, clang++, manipulators

I have a logger class `QueuedLog` which queues up log messages and inserts all the log message(s) in the queue into a `std::ostream` if and when desired. To separate each log message, I wrote a manipulator called `endm` which is used in a similar manner as `std::endl`. For example, here's a use case:

```
QueuedLog log(INFO);

// do stuff

log << "test: 0x" << std::hex << std::uppercase << 15 << endm; // add a log message

// do more stuff

log << "log something else" << endm;

std::cout << log << std::endl; // insert all the queued up log messages into cout

// do more stuff

log << "start another message...";

// calculate something, add it to a log message and end the message
log << std::dec << 42 << endm;

std::cout << log << std::endl; // insert all the queued up log messages into cout

log << "add yet another message" << endm;

// don't need to log that last message after all
// leave it in the QueuedLog instead of inserting it into cout
```

My code compiles fine with Visual C++ but g++ and clang++ fail compilation when I try to use the `endm` manipulator. Here is a minimal version of the `QueuedLog` (which usually resides in a separate header file), with a small example usage demonstrating the problem:

```
#include <ios>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <deque>
#include <stdexcept>

namespace Logger {

enum LogType {
    NONE,   
    DEBUG,  
    INFO,   
    WARN,   
    ERROR,  
    FATAL   
};

// Converts a LogType to a `std::string` which can be prepended to a log message.
std::string prepend_type(LogType type) {
    switch (type) {
        case DEBUG: return std::string("[DEBUG] ");
        case INFO: return std::string("[INFO] ");
        case WARN: return std::string("[WARN] ");
        case ERROR: return std::string("[ERROR] ");
        case FATAL: return std::string("[FATAL] ");
        default: return std::string("");
    }
}

class QueuedLog {
    /* Holds a partially contructed log message.

    A std::stringstream is used instead of a std::string so that non-string data types can be inserted into
    the QueuedLog without requiring conversion. Also, client code can apply I/O manipulators like std::hex.
    */
    std::ostringstream stream;

    std::deque<std::string> messages; // Holds the queued, completed log message(s).

    // The LogType of new messages inserted into the QueuedLog. This can be changed at any time.
    LogType log_type;
public:
    QueuedLog(LogType logtype = NONE) : log_type(logtype) {} // Constructs a QueuedLog with no text and an initial LogType.

    // Inserts a character sequence into the QueuedLog.
    template<typename T> inline QueuedLog& operator<<(const T& message) {
    //inline QueuedLog& operator<<(const std::string& message) { // non-template version doesn't work, either
        // Only prepend with logtype if it is the beginning of the message
        if (stream.str().empty()) stream << prepend_type(log_type);

        stream << message;
        return *this;
    }

    // Overload used for manipulators like QueuedLog::endm()
    inline QueuedLog& operator<<(QueuedLog& (*pf)(QueuedLog&)) {
        (*pf)(*this);
        return *this;
    }

    // Adds the newline character and marks the end of a log message.
    friend inline QueuedLog& endm(QueuedLog& log) {
        log.stream << log.stream.widen('\n');

        // Add the completed message to the messages deque, and reset the stream for the next message
        log.messages.push_back(log.stream.str());
        log.stream.str(""); // clear the underlying string
        log.stream.clear(); // clear any error flags on the stream

        return log;
    }

    /* Inserts all the completed log messages in the QueuedLog object into a std::ostream.

    If the QueuedLog contains an incomplete log message (a message that has not been terminated by QueuedLog::endm())
    then that partial message will not be inserted into the std::ostream.
    */
    friend inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, QueuedLog& log) {
        while (!log.messages.empty()) {
            os << log.messages.front();
            log.messages.pop_front();
        }

        return os;
    }
};

} // end namespace Logger

using namespace Logger;

int main() {
    QueuedLog log(INFO);

    log << "test: 0x" << std::hex << std::uppercase << 15; // compiles by itself with all compilers
    log << endm; // but compilation error w/ g++/clang++ when trying to use endm
    std::cout << log << std::endl;
}
```

Or, this (possibly over-)simplified example:

```
class QueuedLog {
public:
    friend inline void endm() {
    }
};

int main() {
    endm;
}
```

I've attempted to compile it with all three compilers at [rextester](http://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_visual) but it only compiles successfully with Visual C++.

g++ gives the following error:

> `error: ‘endm’ was not declared in this scope`

The error message from clang++ is similar:

> `error: use of undeclared identifier 'endm'`

Why does this work in Visual C++ but not g++ or clang++? How do I fix it for g++/clang++? The solution does not need to work in all three compilers simultaneously, I just want to know how to fix it for g++ and clang++.

Comment: A much shorter [mcve] is available [here](http://ideone.com/44UWla).

Comment: @Robᵩ ideone.com is blocked at work for me. Feel free to edit your MCVE into my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23540764/friend-function-is-not-visible-in-the-class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

friend functions defined inside a class definition are only visible inside that class definition. You need to declare the function outside the class definition. Add this line outside your `class QueuedLog`, but inside your `namespace Logger`:

```
extern QueuedLog& endm(QueuedLog&);
```