# Friend template variadic function

Tags: c++

I'm defining this variadic template function that I want to use use for parameter validation:

```
class Text
{
  template <typename ... T> friend void strfmt(char *dest,int size,const T & ... v)
  {sprintf_s(dest,size,_valchk(v) ...);}

public:
  // other functions in class
};
```

`_valchk` is a set of private member functions of same class.

When I use strfmt, with any kind of parameter, compiler issues an error.

Example:

```
char buf[10];
strfmt(buf,sizeof(buf),"%d",10);
```

> > strfmt: unknown identifier

Why?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The snippet looks like it is placed inside a class definition. Is it? How do you instantiate the template?

Comment: Following [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23541148/3953764), you should *declare* `strfmt` outside of the class.