# why declaring an object of a class before defining it gives error in friend class but not in friend function

Tags: c++

```
class B;
class A {
private:
  int numA;
public:
  A(): numA(12) { }
  // friend function declaration
  friend int add(A, B);
  };
```

this does not give any error on declaring object of class B in friend 
     function,,but this gives,,as firstly class B is declared

```
 class Apple;
 class B {
 private:
 int b;

public:
void showA(Apple d)
{
    // Since B is friend of A, it can access
    // private members of A
    cout << "A::a=" ;
}
};
};
```

this gives an error of incomplete type for object d,,why this is happening though we already declared class apple before,

Comment: When you declare an actual instance (unlike a pointer or reference to) of a class you need the full definition of the class, not only a forward declaration. And if you want to use members of the class, then you definitely need the full definition of the class, otherwise how would the compiler know what members it have?

Comment: Only declaring the function (`class B { void f(A a); };`) possibly would serve better for comparison...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Why does the first example compile?

In your first example, you have a [forward declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/what-are-forward-declarations-in-c) of `class B` followed by a *declaration* of a friend function that uses it in its parameter list:

```cpp
class B;
class A {
  ...
  friend int add(A, B);
};
```

This is allowed because, although `B` is incomplete, we are not defining `add` yet, only declaring an intention to eventually do so.

#### Why does the second example not compile?

In the second example, we have a forward declaration of `class Apple`, followed by a *definition* of `showA`:

```cpp
class Apple;
class B {
  ...
  void showA(Apple d)
  {
    ...
  }
};
```

This time, since we are defining the function, the compiler is obligated to generate code for it.  But because `Apple` is incomplete, the compiler cannot know, for example, how much space in memory to reserve to hold the parameter `d`.  Therefore this is an error.

The question [When can I use a forward declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-can-i-use-a-forward-declaration) explains some of what can and cannot be done with an incomplete (forward-declared) type.

#### The use of 'friend' is irrelevant here

The [`friend`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend) keyword is basically irrelevant here.  `friend` primarily affects access control (in the sense of `public` and `private`), but that's not the issue here.

A detail: `friend` also affects scoping.  Because of `friend`, `add` is not a member of `class A`, but rather [refers to a member of the global scope without actually introducing one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23540764/friend-function-is-not-visible-in-the-class) (it's weird).  But that does not change whether an incomplete type can be used as a parameter.

Comment: You're welcome.  Reminder: if this answers your question, click the checkmark to accept it.