# initializer_list and argument-dependent lookup

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list, argument-dependent-lookup

I'm trying to use an std::initializer_list as an argument in a function that uses argument-dependent lookup (ADL). But I don't get it to work and I don't understand why. The following is a minimal failing example:

```
    #include <initializer_list>
    #include <iostream>

    class Foo {
    public:
      inline friend void bar(std::initializer_list<Foo> v) {
        std::cout << "size = " << v.size() << std::endl;
      }
    };

    void baz(std::initializer_list<Foo> v) {
      std::cout << "size = " << v.size() << std::endl;
    }

    int main(){
      Foo a;
      //bar({a,a});   // error: use of undeclared identifier 'bar'
      baz({a,a});   // works

      return 0;
    }
```

As seen above, an equivalent global function works just fine. Why does the above not work?

I'm using clang on OS X 10.10.

Comment: You're defining the friend implementation inside the class. It needs to be outside, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7785963/2297365). Here's a [working example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b8fd514c67458c99).

Comment: @huu: That is unrelated, if you move the type and the functions to a namespace you will notice that ADL won't find them, whether the function is defined inside or outside of the class.

Comment: `template<class T>
std::initializer_list<T> il(std::initializer_list<T>x){return x;}
` is a somewhat dangerous workaround.  `bar(il({a,a}))` works.  Dangerous because lifetime issues of backing array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe that the problem is that the subexpression<sup>1</sup> `{ a, a }` does not really have a type, and as such it does not have associated types or namespaces which in turn means that ADL does not kick in.  If you have a function in the global namespace, normal lookup will find it, and it will find that `{ a, a }` can match the function call as the initializer for `std::initializer_list<Foo>`.

<sup>1</sup> The syntax `{ a, a }` is called *braced-init-list* and it is not really an expression (or subexpression) in the language.

Comment: As a note, there's an exception for `auto` where `std::initializer_list` is deduced. `auto param = {a, a}; bar(param);` works.

Answer (score 2):

When the compiler sees `bar({a,a})`, it doesn't know the type of the arguments, so it searches for `bar` in the global namespace (`::`), and nowhere else.  If you changed that line to `Foo{a,a}`, then it knows the argument is a `Foo`, and so also searches the `Foo` class for functions.