# Im making a list with iterators and node classes nested in it but for some reason the iterator class is not making the list class a friend

Tags: c++, inner-classes, template-classes

```
 template <class T>
class List
{
class Node
{
public:
    Node()
    {
        next = 0;
        data = 0;
    }
    Node* next;
    T data;
};
Node* head = new Node;
Node* tail = new Node;
int size = 0;
public:
class Iterator
{
 Node* curr;
    friend class List<T>;
public:
 Iterator()
    {
        curr = nullptr;
    }
    friend void fun()
    {
        cout << "helloworld" << endl;
    }
    Iterator begin()
    {
        Iterator it(head->next);
        return it;
    }
};
};
```

created two more class of blocks and programs, programs contained a list of blocks. Implemented iterators for ease of use, But am not able to access its public and private members through list class.

```
int main()
{
List<int> l1;
List<int>::Iterator it;
it = l1.begin();
fun();//iterator befriending neither class nor function
}
```

Error was:
class List has no member begin E0135
begin: is not a member of class list C2039
On vs22

Comment: Please show a [mre]. What functions were not accesible? What error did you get? Where and how did you use `Iterator`? Also the title of your question should _summarize_ the problem, it shouldn't contain half of you question, because it's length is limited as you see.

Comment: sorry, was my first time asking a question here

Comment: int main()
{
 List<int> l1;
 List<int>::Iterator it;
 it = l1.begin();
}

Comment: thiss gives an error that link<int> doesn't have the function begin

Comment: There is not `List<int>::begin()` method in the code you posted. Please post some code that reproduces the problem and the complete error message. Read about [mcve]

Comment: @churill `Iterator begin(){Iterator it(head->next);return it;}

Comment: @HassanAhmad Dont' addd bits and pieces in the comments. Post a [mcve].

Comment: @HassanAhmad Thanks for adding more information :) It seems the `begin`-method should be a member of `List`, not of `Iterator`.

Comment: thanks but even if i try making a friend function in iterator class it is not accessible outside its scope. Would appreciate it if you knew the error.@churill

Comment: @HassanAhmad If you are asking about friend functions in the `Iterator` class, then show some code with a friend function in the `Iterator` class. No-one can fix code you have not shown.

Comment: @john added the function

Comment: @HassanAhmad Apart from the `begin` problem (see comments above and answer below) you just need to add `extern void fun();` before `main`. You can also remove `friend class List<T>;` which is not necessary.

Comment: @HassanAhmad Here's a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785886/access-friend-function-defined-in-class)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access friend function defined in class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785886/access-friend-function-defined-in-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `main`-function you are declaring a `List<int>` and an `List<int>::Iterator`. Where are you calling `begin()`? On `l1`, which is a `List<int>`.

```
List<int> l1;
List<int>::Iterator it;
//   VV -> That's the List<int>
it = l1.begin();
```

Does `List<int>` have a definition of `begin()`? No. This function is defined in `List<int>::Iterator`.

I think you have a misunderstanding about the meaning of `friend` here. It means, the friend class (`List<T>` in this case) is allowed to access `private` or `protected` members of the class (`Iterator` in this case).

It does *not* make `List<T>::head` magically available in `Iterator`. It does *not* make `Iterator::begin` accessible on an instance of `List<T>`.

---

I suggesst the following small change: move the declaration of `begin` from `Iterator` to `List<T>` and provide an appropriate constructor for `Iterator`. You can then remove any friend-declarations, as they are not needed.

Comment: Thanks was really mistaking friend class.

Comment: @HassanAhmad Glad it helped you. If your question is now answered, please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer to mark the question as resolved.